Finding rate of convergence to 1
I have a function of the form $$\frac{1+f(x) + o(x_n) }{1+f(x) + o(g(x))} =\frac{1+f(x) + O(x_n^2) }{1+f(x) + O(x_n^2)},$$
where $|f(x)|\leq 1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 0$. The two O notations are equivalent as the expression comes from Taylor expansions around 0.
I want to find the rate at which it converges to 1 as $n\to\infty$  for fixed $x$. I tried using the Taylor expansion of $1/(1-x)$ to transform it to $$\left(1+f(x) + o(x_n) \right)(1-f(x) + o(x_n)).$$
I keep manipulating the expressions but all I end up is killing all terms not getting anywhere. Any suggestions here?

For what x it should converge?

Should $o(\epsilon)$ here be $o(x)$?

Sorry yes it was a typo. I changed the notation now and added the extra information
